# Is there a way to move(translate) a group in a vector drawable in android?

Tags: java, android, android-vectordrawable

I had a vector drawable which looks like [image: scale vector drawable] and the put the path of red triangle part in a group and gave it a name so that I can move(translate) it horizontally depending on certain values. But I couldn't find a way to do it programmatically. The translateX part works if I wrote it on the vector xml(android:translateX) but I wanted it to happen dynamically. I have found one library in [Github](https://github.com/harjot-oberai/VectorMaster)  but it didn't work. Here is the code I tried it in.

```
        // Instantiate the custom drawable
        VectorMasterDrawable vectorMasterDrawable = new VectorMasterDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_horizontalrange);
        // Set background drawable for ImageView
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView_scale);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(vectorMasterDrawable);
        // find the correct path using name
        GroupModel outline = vectorMasterDrawable.getGroupModelByName("indicator");
        outline.setTranslateX(12);
```

and this is my vector file

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="640dp"
    android:height="640dp"
    android:viewportWidth="640"
    android:viewportHeight="640">
  <path
      android:pathData="M29.16,300.77L215.93,300.77L215.93,320L29.16,320L29.16,300.77Z"
      android:fillColor="#0076ff"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M215.93,300.77L402.7,300.77L402.7,320L215.93,320L215.93,300.77Z"
      android:fillColor="#ffd31a"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M398.41,300.77L592.33,300.77L592.33,320L398.41,320L398.41,300.77Z"
      android:fillColor="#0fe871"/>

  <group android:name="indicator"
      android:translateX="12">
  <path
      android:name="triangle_1"
      android:pathData="M36.12,291.16L43.09,281.54L29.16,281.54L15.23,281.54L22.19,291.16L29.16,300.77L36.12,291.16Z"
      android:fillColor="#e4052f"/>
  </group>

</vector>
```

Comment: your question doesn't really have anything to do with android studio as an IDE, remember that you're just using it to build your app, but your code won't be any different because you're using it. rest of your question seems fine though